# Projection of properties of objects in NSArray/NSSet collections

Tags: ios, objective-c, projection, nsset

I have an array of objects that I convert to a `NSSet`:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@{ @"someProp": @21, @"unnecessaryProp": @"tada" }, ... ];
NSSet *collection = [NSSet setWithArray:arr];
```

I would like to project the properties I want (by key) out of each object in the set and end up with a new array like:

```
NSArray *projectedArray = [collection allObjects]; // @[@{ "someProp": @21 }, ... ], "unnecessaryProp" has been removed
```

Besides enumeration, is there any other way, perhaps `NSPredicate`?

***NOTE***: *The objects in the array are subclasses of `NSObject`, in my example I mentioned a `NSDictionary`*

Comment: From a comment on a deleted answer: "But I do not care about the values, I just want to filter by key, return a new array containing only objects with a set of keys I want" Then what you want is called a projection. `NSPredicate`s don't do projections.

Comment: Oh, did not know the term ... thanks for it, I'll update the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `NSPredicate` does not do projections, you would end up enumerating the set. I would enumerate it with a block, and project the keys in the individual dictionaries like this:

```
NSArray *keep= @["someProp"];
NSMutableArray *res = [NSMutableArray array];
[collection enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id dict, BOOL *stop) {
    NSArray *values = [dict objectsForKeys:keep notFoundMarker:@""];
    [res addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keep]];
}];
```

**EDIT :** (in response to comments)

> I should have mentioned that the objects inside the array are subclasses of NSObject and objectsForKeys is not a method.

Then you could use [MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r)'s suggestion to build a dictionary using KVC:

```
NSArray *keep= @["someProp"];
NSMutableArray *res = [NSMutableArray array];
[collection enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [res addObject:[obj dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keep]];
}];
```

Comment: Probably I should have mentioned that the objects inside the array are subclasses of `NSObject` and `objectsForKeys` is not a method.

Comment: @rolandjitsu Your post is showing `NSDictionary` objects `@{ "someProp": 21, "unnecessaryProp": @"tada" }` inside `NSArray`. If the objects inside are your objects, not dictionaries, you would have to do the individual projections manually as well.

Comment: @rolandjitsu: You can use `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys`, which can be applied to any object, uses KVC, and returns a dictionary with the values for the given keys.

Comment: @MartinR, I just used that method and then used this answer's suggestion.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, that is my mistake, I should have added the proper description

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, a side question, if I were to alter one of the properties of each of those objects, what would be the best approach (I convert the set to `NSData` and on of the props on each object is a `NSConcreteUUID` and it needs to be a string)?

Comment: @rolandjitsu I would exclude the name of that property from the `keep` array, and add two lines to the iterating block to fetch the `NSConcreteUUID` property, and to add its value to the result after converting to string. Unfortunately, you would need to make the inner dictionaries mutable.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing, but I though there might be some method that can do that in place. Thanks for the help @dasblinkenlight :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the values for one property of the objects in a collection of type `NSSet` or `NSArray` or their subclasses, you can use the KVC method `valueForKey:`

```
NSArray *dogs = @[@{@"name" : @"Fido",
                @"toys" : @[@"Ball", @"Kong"]},
                @{@"name" : @"Rover",
                @"toys" : @[@"Ball", @"Rope"]},
                @{@"name" : @"Spot",
                @"toys" : @[@"Rope", @"Kong"]}];

NSArray *vals = [set valueForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@", vals);
```

The above code prints the following on the console:

```
2014-05-16 09:26:58.293 xctest[17223:303] (
    Fido,
    Rover,
    Spot
)
```

If you need the values of several properties of the objects in the collection, use `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`. Given the same array as in the previous example, the following code...

```
NSDictionary *dict = [dogs dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[@"name", @"toys"]];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

produces an array of dictionaries, and logs the following output:

```
2014-05-16 09:35:34.793 xctest[17275:303] {
    name =     (
        Fido,
        Rover,
        Spot
    );
    toys =     (
                (
            Ball,
            Kong
        ),
                (
            Ball,
            Rope
        ),
                (
            Rope,
            Kong
        )
    );
}
```

This works regardless of whether the objects in the target collections are instances of `NSDictionary` or of custom classes.

Answer (score -1):

you can use indexOfObjectPassingTest on your array or NSSet.

```
__block NSUInteger  maxIdex = [_myArrray count]-1;
__block NSMutableIndexSet* objToRemove = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]init];

    [_myArrray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop){

        MyObject *obj = (MyObject*)object;
        if(....){

            [objToRemove addIndex:[_myArrray indexOfObject:obj]];
        }

        *stop = (idx == maxIdex);
        return *stop;
    }];

 [_myArrray removeObjectsAtIndexes:objToRemove];
```